# How to make python module run in dist-packages folders in the desired order?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, python, bluetooth, python-2.7

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed a python module called PyBluez. When I compile and install the module from source code, the output is installed in the folder `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bluetooth`.

When I install using "apt-get", the files are installed in the folder `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

When I run python code using PyBluez module, which packages will run first? The one in /usr/local/... or /usrlib/... ? How do I check?

What if I want /usr/local/... to run first? How do I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Open a python shell and type:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

/usr/local should normally be first, so it will be searched first.